# how to get new line without enter key

Tags: json, elasticsearch

On windows,I am try to edit my own json file [image]

I use Enter key to get a new line. when I use git bash with command `curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/customer/external/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary  @act.json`
 it just throw some error `action_request_validation_exception` ,and i use \n on the fisrt line,it still doesn't work,then I use data generated from [JSON Generator](http://www.json-generator.com/) my git bash can read it well.I read some resource, it is related to `new line`.so here comes my question,when I want to edit my own json file,how to make a new line just like the genrated file from json generator .thanks a lot!

Comment: Your file doesn't look like valid JSON. Try paste your text into https://jsonlint.com/ and validate.

Comment: @Vlam  Thanks,even through , <a href=" jsonlint.com"> jsonlint.com</a> make no difference for me.

Comment: @Vlam Because it's no JSON! it's an ndjson: http://ndjson.org/